# Making sense of date-time and datatypes in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqldatatypes

I'm learning SQL and SQLite at the moment, and from what I understand, SQLite doesn't support a `datetime` datatype.

However, when I run the command `PRAGMA table_info(Orders);` it's showing one column as being of type `datetime`.

I've read that `In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.` taken from here https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

I'm trying to understand what exactly this means, which may help to explain.

Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the column `type` when you execute:

```
PRAGMA table_info(tablename)
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('tablename');
```

is the data type that was used for the definition of the column in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

SQLite allows the use of anything (even nothing), as long as it is not  a reserved word, as a data type.

This:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  column0 integer primary key, 
  column1 integer,
  column2 text,
  column3 real, 
  column4 string,
  column5 something,
  column6 Jack,
  column7, -- no data type defined
  column8 real char int -- ??,
  column9 datetime  
);
```

is a valid statement!

From all the above column definitions, SQLite will enforce type checking only for the column `column0` which is defined as `integer primary key`.

From [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3/Storage Classes and Datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes):

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
> KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

When you define a column as `datetime`, don't expect SQLite to understand your intention and set any internal constraints so that the values you store in it will be datetime-like.
Actually, by the rules described in [Determination Of Column Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity), this column will have `NUMERIC` affinity.

Of course you can store datetime values in a column, as described in [Date and Time Datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype), by using `INTEGER`, `REAL` or `TEXT` data type, depending on the form of the datetimes that you want: `Unix Time`s, `Julian day numbers` or `ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")` strings respectively.

In conclusion, SQLite will never complain for any value in any column defined as any data type (except for `integer primary key`).
It is your responsibility to make sure that you store values in the proper format that you can read/write, make calculations, compare etc.
For example, never store text datetimes in any other format than `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"` because all [SQLite's datetime functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) work with this format only.

Comment: Perfect thank you for this detailed explanation. That cleared it up completely!

Answer (score 0):

To amplify @[forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701993/451601)'s excellent answer, you can make up for SQLite's weak type-checking by using `CHECK` constraints in your table definitions. I frequently do that to enforce integers or string lengths, and you could use SQLite's date functions to verify that the value can be parsed as a date and lies between two values.

Comment: Thank you! All making sense now. Thanks for chiming in.